# Uno - macOS app crashes on startup when debugging without any errors - WASM stuck on Splash screen

Tags: c#, webassembly, uno

I have started a new project using the dotnet new unoapp command however, my macOS target crashes when I start debugging it (Run only works fine).

Also, when my WASM target launches it gets stuck on the Splash screen and the only logs I see in the browser are:

[21:39:24] fail: DevToolsProxy[0]
Failed to load http://localhost:5000/package_73812bf9450c7562c50164bdc887a65ceeb12235/managed/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll (An error occurred while sending the request.)
[21:39:24] fail: DevToolsProxy[0]
Failed to load http://localhost:5000/package_73812bf9450c7562c50164bdc887a65ceeb12235/managed/System.Text.Encoding.dll (An error occurred while sending the request.)
[21:39:24] fail: DevToolsProxy[0]
Failed to load http://localhost:5000/package_73812bf9450c7562c50164bdc887a65ceeb12235/managed/Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable.dll (An error occurred while sending the request.)
[21:39:24] fail: DevToolsProxy[0]

http://…/uno-bootstrap.js:75GET http://localhost:5000/_framework/unohotreload 0
http://…azor-hotreload.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
uno-bootstrap.js:87Failed to apply initial metadata delta TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5000/_framework/bl

My question is more about troubleshooting steps and where to get a meaningful debug output in order to investigate the root cause of the issue, as nothing is printed in the console output when such a crash occurs.